# Notepad ++ Regular Expressions for Find and delete a line

Tags: regex

i have a subtitle just like below

```
5
00:00:14,030 --> 00:00:15,840
Anya's killing it, don't you think?

6
00:00:15,850 --> 00:00:17,230
She's dedicated.

7
00:00:17,270 --> 00:00:19,890
She has made some shrewd choices.

8
00:00:20,050 --> 00:00:23,200
Sometimes it feels like
purging is the only answer.

9
00:00:23,230 --> 00:00:24,720
You know, I was talking
to my dad about you.
```

i want to delete the timing i mean for example this "`00:00:23,230 --> 00:00:24,720`" i wanna to delete all of this timing and re timing the subtitle so what can i do ?

i think i should find the line start with `0` and then delete whole of the line
i need a regular expressions

Comment: What do you mean with "re timing the subtitle"? What is your expected result?

Comment: "i think i should find the line start with 0 and then delete whole of the line" - sounds like an option, have you tried it? (`^0.+$`)

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at [this reference](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum timing is less than 10 hours, and no other line starts with `0`, you could do what you suggested.

Alternatively, search for lines containing `-->`, i.e. search for `^.*-->.*$` and replace it with nothing (Set Search Mode to *Regular expression*).

However this will leave you with empty lines. If you want to remove those as well, use the *Mark* tab on the Find dialog, check *Bookmark line*, and click on *Mark all*. Then select Search → Bookmarks → Remove Bookmarked Lines.